# Neural Text Simplification with no appropriate dataset

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, machine-translation

I'm currently starting a research project focused on NLP.

One of the steps involved in this project will be the development of a text simplification system, probably using a neural encoder-decoder architecture.

For most Text Simplification research available, the most commonly used dataset is one derived from pairing Wikipedia entries in both English and Simplified English. My problem arises from the fact that the focus of my research is not on the English Language, but rather in Portuguese, specifically Portugal Portuguese.

There exists no Simple Portuguese Wikipedia page and it seems that there exists no publicly available text simplification dataset in Portugal Portuguese at all. Due to this fact I'm curious if there would be any way of tackling this problem. Maybe having a dataset simply of complex Portuguese and simple portuguese, but with no pairings, although I'm not quite sure how that could be formulated to train a NN with.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you’re asking about can reasonably be called “unsupervised text style transfer”. You have two styles of text: simple and complex. Your goal is to switch text from one style to the other, even though you’ve never seen the simplified version of a complex sentence or the complicated version of a simple sentence.

One work that tackles this well is [He et al. (2020)](https://openreview.net/forum?id=HJlA0C4tPS).
By means of parameter-tying, they show how to do this transfer task you describe with only one translation model that they train and two pre-trained language models. You should also check the papers that it cites and papers that cite it for more ideas.